# Cryptic Family Reunion: Pocket Edition

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Dad's shock troop to stand on Ontario borders (7)
2. Desperado kidnaps community leader, extorting boundless loot from Auntie (9)
3. Nephew is hacking US-China net (10)
4. Grandpa called, "Turn around, dance, turn around, ..." (7)
5. Grandma called, "...turn and dance" (7)
6. Niece obtaining a source of caffeine (5)
7. Brother's ill-begotten fortune finally confiscated (7)
8. Son's baseball team: doubles, but no walk (6)
9. Daughter's gerbil bypasses hideaway (5)
10. Sister to get some sun all over, including bum-bum (6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are all

> Marsupials

Answers.

> 1. POTOROO = (TROOP)* + O(ntari)O.
>  2. BANDICOOT = BANDIT containing C and l(OO)t.
>  3. ANTECHINUS = (US-CHINA NET)*
>  4. WALLABY = BALL (dance) backwards with WAY (turn) around it.
>  5. DUNNART = (TURN AND)*
>  6. KOALA = KOLA obtaining A
>  7. BETTONG = (BEGOTTEN)* - (fortun)E.
>  8. CUSCUS = CUBS x 2 and remove the BB (indicating "Base on balls" or "walk").
>  9. BILBY = ger(BIL BY)passes.
>  10. NUMBAT = TAN< including (BUM)*.
>
>  Number 8 was solved by LeppyR64 before me.

As for the title (thanks to El-Guest in the comments)

> A distinctive characteristic of marsupials is that they carry their young in a pouch or pocket.

Comment: Almost there! #4 is not correct. And on #8, rot13(OO vf "Onfr ba Onyyf", gur fgnaqneq nooerivngvba sbe n jnyx va onfronyy fpbevat)

Comment: @JeremyDover Thanks, I think I've got #4 now.

Comment: Right answer, but I had the word play as rot13(LNJ ("ghea") nebhaq ONYY ("qnapr") gb trg LONYYNJ, "ghea nebhaq" gb trg JNYYNOL) Does that make sense to you as a solver?

Comment: And of course you’ll note that a defining feature of the theme that you’ve found is that they have _pockets_ (or pouches)...

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot the title! Thanks @El-Guest

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

8. Son's baseball team: doubles, but no walk (6)

> Baseball team  = CUBS
>  walk = BB
>  CUBSCUBS - BB = CUSCUS

Comment: Ah yeah I just got it, will give credit on mine.

Comment: Great work on the rest @hexomino :)